# Two two-way switches in same gang box on same circuit. Only works when both are "On". What to do?

Tags: wiring, switch, rewire

I have 2 light switches in the same gang box, both connected to a ceiling light. They both appear to be 2-way switches as they both have "On/Off" printed on them. They do not work like 3-way switches, but appear to be 2-way connected in series. In order to toggle the light, one must be in the on position, and then the other can toggle the light normally. If either is in the "off" position, the light will be off, regardless of the other switch state.

What should I do? Do I remove one of the switches, and if so, do I just connect hot and neutral, and push gnd to the back of the box? What do I do with the empty space? Do I install an outlet to put in the extra gang just for the heck of it? Since they seem to be wired in series, I'm assuming this outlet will be tied to the switch?

I'm trying to figure out what the original intent was. It just occurred to me it could be intended for a ceiling fan, but replaced with a light-only fixture and then someone re-wired incorrectly? Is this possible?

Comment: Turn power off at the breaker. Remove the face plate. Unscrew the switches from the wall. Pull the switches out so you can see all the wiring. **DO NOT DISCONNECT ANYTHING**. Take clear, focused pics of the switches and the wiring going into the box. [Edit] those into your post. Carefully reassemble so you can turn the power back on until you get an answer.

Comment: Yes, your assumption about having been a light/fan control is entirely possible. As are about 100 other things. The key is what to do with it now. You certainly could replace 1 switch with outlets if that would make sense here, or you could get a cover plate that will simply cover the empty switch spot until you decide you need something else there. Don't do anything, though, until you get the pics. You'll get nicely detailed instructions once we get pics.

Comment: It sounds like the power comes into SW1 and from there gose to SW2 and than to the ceiling box. All the Neutrals should be twisted together. Photo's would decrease guessing/problems. Use a "double switch plate" that has a 'blank/switch' configuration.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite common when someone changes a light switch in a 2 gang or 2 independent switch unit they get the feeder mixed up so only 1 switch has an always hot and they feed the switched hot to the 2nd switch.
A photo would make this easier but there is a wire that connects to both switches.
Move that wire on switch 1 to the other side and your problem will probably be resolved. It may be 2 wires under 1 side and 1 on the other maybe more but the hot needs to be moved, if light 1 is on all the time after that the wire to the fixture needs to be on the switched side of switch , if you provide a photo we could give you a better description,